# VBA Excel Custom Userform with Checkboxes, wont work in macro code

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I need a little VBA help. I created a custom user form with options yes, n/a, no and a commandbutton to enter. Now i wanted to add the logic, it should filter only the shown rows. It always returns error on my first if line (if checkbox1.enabled ). I already tried if checkbox1.value Is True, but it still wont work. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim runner As Variant, row As Variant
    row = 9

    If CheckBox1.Enabled Is True Then
        For Each runner In row
            If Not runner.Hidden Then
                If cell(row, 10).Value Is Empty Then
                    runner.Hide
                End If
            End If

        Next runner
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue in your first `If`, you need to change it to

```
If CheckBox1.Enabled = True Then
```

This is the correct syntax to check if a value is `True` in VBA. The following is also an acceptable syntax:

```
If CheckBox1.Enabled Then
```

If nothing is provided in such validation, VBA will check if the value is `True` by default. Similarly, to check if value is `False` you can do:

```
If CheckBox1.Enabled = False Then
```

Or also

```
If Not CheckBox1.Enabled Then
```

Once you fix the current issue, you will find another problem in the following line:

```
If cell(row, 10).Value Is Empty Then
```

To check if a cell is Empty, the correct syntax would be

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(row, 10).Value) Then
```

Please note that I'm using `Cells` and not `cell`. Plus, this will check for the global reference of a cell, which in turn looks for the cell in the active worksheet. Supposing you want to check for the cell in `Sheet1`, but user activates `Sheet2` while using your UserForm, the cell in `Sheet2` will be checked instead. To avoid this, is advisable that you make a proper reference to the cell, like the following:

```
If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetName").Cells(row, 10).Value) Then
```

There are also some problems in your `For` loop, if your code is exactly as you posted. It will probably not work, but I'd need a better understanding on what is going on there in order to assist you.

I hope this helps.